QML ListView drag and drop snapback animation
I have a ListView in which I reorder items using drag and drop. The content of the items are defined using a Loader, and the drag and drop is managed by a MouseArea and a DropArea.
Here is a simplified version of my component code:
Rectangle {
  id: component

  property Component content
  property alias model: listView.model

  width: 300
  height: 300

  ListView {
    id: listView

    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: MouseArea {
      id: itemDelegate

      property var item: model
      property int itemIndex: index

      property bool held: false

      height: container.height
      anchors.left: parent ? parent.left  : undefined
      anchors.right: parent ? parent.right : undefined

      drag.target: held ? container : undefined
      drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
      pressAndHoldInterval: 0
      onPressAndHold: held = true
      onReleased: held = false


      states: State {
        when: itemDelegate.held
        ParentChange { target: container; parent: listView}
      }

      Rectangle {
        id: container

        Drag.active: itemDelegate.held
        Drag.source: itemDelegate
        Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
        Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2

        height: loader.height
        width: itemDelegate.width
        color: "red"

        Loader {
          id: loader

          property var item: itemDelegate.item
          property int index: itemIndex

          width: parent.width
          sourceComponent: content
        }
      }

      DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onEntered: component.model.move(drag.source.itemIndex, itemDelegate.itemIndex)
      }
    }
  }
}

It works. My question is :
How can I animate smoothly when I release items and they snap back at their place in the list ?
Right now, they instantly teleport from wherever I was dragging them to where they should now be in the list.
I would like these animations to be smooth and could not find a working solution, mainly because the parenting change handled by my State seems to be automatically reverted when I release the mouse button; and I could did not succeeded at linking an animation to this automatic reparenting.
TY for your help !
